# Sort and divide the graph in positive and negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have attached my codes and graph obtained below. I actually need to separate the positive and negative barplots in the graph.

```
city_summary$colour<-ifelse(city_summary$x < 0, "Negative","Positive")
city_summary$hjust<-ifelse(city_summary$x >0,1.3,-0.3)
p1<-ggplot(city_summary, aes(x=City, y=x, label="",hjust=hjust))+
  geom_text(aes(y=0,colour=colour))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity", aes(fill=colour))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Positive="steelblue1",Negative="firebrick1"))
p1
```

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTs2z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is difficult to reproduce without a data set, but using `reorder` in your `aes(` statement should work (considering by "separate" you mean group them together along the x-axis):

```
library(ggplot2)

city_summary$colour<-ifelse(city_summary$x < 0, "Negative","Positive")
city_summary$hjust<-ifelse(city_summary$x >0,1.3,-0.3)

p1<-ggplot(city_summary, aes(x= reorder(City, x) , y=x, label="",hjust=hjust))+
  geom_text(aes(y=0,colour=colour))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity", aes(fill=colour))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Positive="steelblue1",Negative="firebrick1"))
p1
```